# Identify plant with narrow straplike leaves and red flower

Tags: identification, flowering, urban-gardening

We have been having this green narrow leaved plant for years. It flowers occasionally as in the image. Some say it is from the family of bromeliads but its structure looks so different.

[image]

Comment: If you dont get a positive ID, could you wait a couple of days and post another photo of the flowers please? Thinking of Bilbergia spp. (Bromeliaceae)